# How to prevent UILabel.textColor to change in a dequeueReusableCell when scrolling?

Tags: swift, uitableview, scroll, uilabel

I have this code in my ViewController named `PlayViewController`:

```
var words = [String]()

var numberOfRevealedLabels = 1

var indexGA = 0
var indexWA = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    playTableView.delegate = self
    playTableView.dataSource = self

    view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    let swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.respondToSwipeGesture))
    swipeRight.direction = .right
    view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)

    let swipeLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.respondToSwipeGesture))
    swipeLeft.direction = .left
    view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellIdentifier = "PlayTableViewCell"
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? PlayTableViewCell else {
        fatalError("The dequeued cell is not an instance of PlayTableViewCell.")
    }

    cell.wordLabel.text = words[indexPath.row]

    var count = 0
    while (count < words.count)
    {
        if (indexPath.row == count) {
            if (count == 0) {
                cell.wordLabel.isHidden = false
            }
            if (indexGA - 1 == count) {
                cell.wordLabel.textColor = UIColor.green
            } else if (indexWA - 1 == count) {
                cell.wordLabel.textColor = UIColor.red
            }
        }
        count += 1
    }

    cell.wordLabel.isHidden = !(indexPath.row <= numberOfRevealedLabels - 1)

    return cell
}

@objc func respondToSwipeGesture(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    if let swipeGesture = gesture as? UISwipeGestureRecognizer {
        switch swipeGesture.direction {

        case UISwipeGestureRecognizer.Direction.right:
            indexGA = numberOfRevealedLabels
            numberOfRevealedLabels += 1
            playTableView.reloadData()

        case UISwipeGestureRecognizer.Direction.left:
            indexWA = numberOfRevealedLabels
            numberOfRevealedLabels += 1
            playTableView.reloadData()

        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

So basically, the app does the following stuff:

- It prompts the first word of the list in black.
- Swiping right changes the color of the word to green, left to red. Swipes also prompts the next word in black.
- `numberOfRevealedLabels` counts the number of words currently displayed, `indexGA` helps to track the position of the word to turn in green, same for `indexWA` for the red ones.

When I scroll down to read the next word (I start scrolling at the twelfth word), it's prompted in the same color of the previous word (green if I swiped right or red if left). Also, the first words of the list change their color randomly (either black, green or red).

**I've read threads like [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38482561/table-view-cells-changing-colors-when-scrolling-swift) [ones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35953138/swift-2-tableview-scrolling-changes-data) and I know it's because of `dequeueReusableCell`.**

My code has no `else` condition. When adding one to set the `.textColor` to black turns all the words but the last two swiped to black.

To fix the `else` statement, I can code something like this:

```
else {
    if (cell.wordLabel.textColor == UIColor.green) {
        cell.wordLabel.textColor = UIColor.green
    } else if (cell.wordLabel.textColor == UIColor.red) {
        cell.wordLabel.textColor = UIColor.red
    } else {
        cell.wordLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, it didn't solve my problem, labels in cells keep changing colors in a weird fashion (plus, it adds a few more ugly LOC to a not so logic loop).

Last thing I've tried: to set `wordLabel.textColor = UIColor.black`in `PlayTableViewCell.swift`but it didn't fixed anything.

I'm out of ideas/logic, any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You should set `cell.wordLabel.textColor = UIColor.black` right after you call `cell.wordLabel.text = words[indexPath.row]`.

So it should look like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellIdentifier = "PlayTableViewCell"
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? PlayTableViewCell else {
        fatalError("The dequeued cell is not an instance of PlayTableViewCell.")
    }
    cell.wordLabel.text = words[indexPath.row]
    cell.wordLabel.textColor = UIColor.black //HERE

    var count = 0
    while (count < words.count)
    {
        if (indexPath.row == count) {
            if (count == 0) {
                cell.wordLabel.isHidden = false
            }
            if (indexGA - 1 == count) {
                cell.wordLabel.textColor = UIColor.green
            } else if (indexWA - 1 == count) {
                cell.wordLabel.textColor = UIColor.red
            }
        }
        count += 1
    }

    cell.wordLabel.isHidden = !(indexPath.row <= numberOfRevealedLabels - 1)

    return cell
}
```

Adding an `else` doesn't solve the problem because it's placed in a nested `if statement`. A cell with the color can still be reused since you aren't setting a default color before any `if statements`. Adding it outside of all `if statements` will ensure the color is always black unless a condition is met.

Comment: Hi @arjun-s and thanks for your help! Unfortunately, I've already tried this and it doesn't work: all the words turn black except the one just swiped. Every time the ``func tableView`` returns a new cell, the previous words jump back to black except the second to last which deals with the swipe.

Comment: To go further with your idea, I've just tried to implement the ``else``condition I've written in my question + a color check before the while loop: ``if (cell.wordLabel.textColor == UIColor.green) {
            cell.wordLabel.textColor == UIColor.green
        } else if (cell.wordLabel.textColor == UIColor.red) {
            cell.wordLabel.textColor = UIColor.red
        } else {
            cell.wordLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
        }`` The problem here is how can I persist color attributes of a label inside a reusable cell? I can't code smthg like ``cell[0].wordLabel.textColor``